# Email async validation with facebook registration form

Tags: facebook, validation, asynchronous, email-validation, user-registration

As facebook says

```
For privacy reasons, the input to your function will be only the custom fields you requested, on blur or submit.
```

Indeed email is not custom field but when user clicks on "x" (cross) to fill details manually then still `form.email` remain `undefined` ?

Is this a facebook bug , is there any fix/ solution for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have found a fix for it by using 'view' property

In fields list I added

```
fields="[
 {'name':'email','view':'prefilled'},
 {'name':'xemail','view': 'not_prefilled','description':'Email Address:','type':'text'}]";
```

Now email is used with fb and xemail is used without fb and my async validators which are needed in case of without fb uses form.xemail.